# I used bazel to build a shared library. But, how to automatically install all headers in specific directory

Tags: c++, tensorflow, shared-libraries, bazel

I'm a newbie to bazel. I build a lib from tensorflow source. But How to automatically generate include directory, including all headers. Thank Thank you! !

now I got a libxxx.so(using tensorflow/core/so_many_header.h) from bazel build. I need some include files, when using libxxx.so. But where are headers files?.

Comment: What do you want to obtain exactly? How do you plan to use those directories?

Comment: yes, I built a libxxx.so. But how to install it to /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include/xxx

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good answer right now, the best I can recommend is making a run target that copy those files in the good directories.

Comment: Could you open a feature request on [the bazel tracker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel) for this? Sounds like something we should support. Thanks!